# Android ListView disable clicks and context menu on header view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I set a header view using `getListView().addHeaderView(view);` and it currently gets treated in the same way as all of the other list rows with regards to clicks and context menus. How can I make the header view act like more of a header? Alternatively, how can I just add some content above the `ListView` that is not part of the `ListView` itself?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Look at the second and third parameter of the [addHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) method. You can simply disable interaction with

```
getListView().addHeaderView(view, null, false);
```

Comment: You certainly can. SO enforces a time limit on accepts so I couldn't accept immediately.

Answer (score 0):

**simple way to disable the header clicks is to put the below two lines before interacting with list item clicks**

```
 if(position == 0)
        return;
```

and then

*code interacting with item clicks*